# Use sed to delete all but a certain pattern

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How do I get just the link part in the http-source of a link?

I have

```
<a href="http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/">Unix &amp; Linux
```

and would like to get just

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/
```

I tried

```
sed 's/^.*(http.*)".*$/\1/g'
```

but that gives an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `awk`, `bash` or `ksh` here? Because either awk or extended shell globs can do the job much more easily then `sed`'s regexes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/.*(http[^"]*)".*/\1/g'
```

On Mac OSX, try:

```
sed -E 's/.*(http[^"]*)".*/\1/g'
```

#### Notes

There are several items to note about this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/^.*(http.*)".*$/\1/g'
```

1. The `^` is unnecessary.  sed's regular expressions are always *greedy*.  That means that, if a regex that begins with `.*` matches at all, it will always match from the beginning of the line.
2. To make `(` into a grouping character, it can either be escaped or extended regex can be turned on with the `-r` flag (`-E` on OSX).  This flag often greatly reduces the number of escapes that you will need.
3. Also, because regex are greedy, `(http.*)"` will match to the last double quote on the line, not the first.  The URL will, however, end with the first double-quote.  Instead, use `(http[^"]*)"` and the match will never extend beyond the first `"`.
4. The dollar sign in `.*$` is also superfluous.  Again, because regex are greedy, if a regular expression that ends with `.*` matches, it will match to the end of the line.

Comment: so for a quick fix in my case it would be `-r` which would be `sed -r 's/^.*(http.*)".*$/\1/g'` -- but I will keep your tips in mind, thx! great answer! ;-)

Comment: @rubo77 Yes, that is correct.  But, do watch out for lines with more than one `"` on them.

Answer (score 2):

Just a lack of escaping:

```
sed 's/^.*\(http.*\)".*$/\1/g'
```

(I can never remember which ones expect `()` and which ones expect `\(\)` either.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
echo '<a href="http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/">Unix & Linux' \
| awk -F\" '{print $2}'
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20661/
```